# Convert Json into Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary

Following Json is from Mongodb by querying collection.find() method. How do I convert this Json into Dictionary in Python? I want to map BMW as key and Series 3 as value in my dictionary.

Python:

```
content = list(collection.find({"_id": "sample_abc"}, {"Car":1, "_id":0}))
print (content)
```

Console:

```
[{'Car': [{'BMW': 'series 3'}, {'Audi': 'A4'}]}]
```

Comment: Have you looked into, for example, [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content[0]['Car'][0]` may be `{'BMW': 'series 3'}`

Answer (score 4):

This will do it:

```
import json
q = json.loads(content)
```